# How to compile binaries that work on older Linux distros?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc, ubuntu-14.04

I have Ubuntu 16.10.  How can I compile a C++ program so that the binary will work correctly on Ubuntu 14.04, or any other Linux distribution of similar age?  (I am only interested in x86-64.)

Is this achievable with the default compiler on 16.10 (gcc 6.2) or do I need to install and use the same compiler 14.04 had (gcc 4.8)?  If I need the older compiler, do I need the `-multilib` packages?

I am interested both in a general (distro-agnostic) explanation of what is needed for compatibility and more specific hints on how to do it on my version of Ubuntu.

Comment: In my case I needed virtual machines to test that the program actually ran on the target distros, so I just built the executable on the older distros and kept testing until they all built the executable and all could run an executable built on any of them.

Comment: @user4581301 In an ideal world, I would do that. But unfortunately, I am doing this in my free time, using personal resources only, which are stretched to the limit. I already have too many virtual machines, so I can build on the three main OSs. I asked others to test on such old Linux versions. I have gotten this working in the past with an older Ubuntu (15.x?), by installing gcc 4.8.  Unfortunately, I lost my notes from then ... I was also hoping that there would be a way without installing the old toolchain.

Comment: Most importantly you are going to need suitably old versions of the libraries you're compiling against,i.e. which will be present on those older distribution releases.

Comment: @DanielJour Is there a way to install them on a newer distro?  Since it is possible to cross-compile for a completely different architecture or ABI (say, ARM or x32), it seemed reasonable to me that it should also be possible to target older releases on the same architecture.

Comment: @Szabolcs Hm ... you could attempt to do a minimal installation of said old distribution in a chroot. This will bring in the old libraries, compiling from within the chroot should be possible. Less CPU "overhead" than a virtual machine, but still (depending on how "minimal" you can get a distro) some space overhead.

Comment: @Szabolcs nope, tehre is no real way to keep two library of different version, this is what things like gobolinux. A chroot is another valid solution IF the architecture of the two machine are the same (or similar, in a way that you can disable some feature to get compatibility); finally if you manage to use static library that does not depend from other system library, you can just compile like you would normally.

Answer (score -1):

The ugly solution would be to link everything (including c++ runtime) statically to produce huge monolithic executable that would not depend on system libraries as much (that is how they do it in go language for example). Another ugly solution would be to set up some CI and build everything on all supported systems. However this most likely would mean writing everything with an oldest supported system in mind and struggle with compatibility issues.